# Office Fabric React - snapToStep not working on Slider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react

I have this code:

```
   <Slider
        value={state.filters.radius}
        onChange={value => {
          console.log(value);
        }}
        step={5}
        max={20}
        // @ts-ignore
        snapToStep
      />
```

I have the this version `^7.93.1`. 
Snap to step is not working and even typescript reports an error that `snapToStep` prop doesn't exist

Comment: What you have appears to function correctly here in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-sammet-r3k9d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). I think this is just a typescript issue. Do you need to import the [slider props interface](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/slider#ISliderProps) definition?

Comment: Solved it by changing the version to `^6.211.4`. I have no idea why it works now. Although now i get an error `Cannot find module 'office-ui-fabric-react'`